# How to check userdata type without throwing an error

Tags: c++, lua

I am writing some library (in C++) for lua, where I use some custom type, for example: `my_type`. `my_type` is `userdata` with metatable `my_type`. I can check it in the library (in C++ code) using the function `luaL_checkudata` and it works fine. But! If I use `luaL_checkudata(state, 1, "my_type")` and the type of the object is not `my_type` it throws an error. So, when I want to check the type and not get an error and get just `true` or `false`, what can I use? The function `lua_isuserdata` does not check the metatable of the userdata.

I'm using Lua 5.1.

Comment: Have you introduced the type to Lua correctly, such as using `luaL_newmetatable(L, "my_type")`

Comment: Newer Lua versions provide a `luaL_testudata` function for exactly this purpose. You can find a sample implementation [here](https://github.com/keplerproject/lua-compat-5.3/blob/master/c-api/compat-5.3.c#L284) or in the official Lua source for Lua 5.2 and up (`luaL_*` functions only use the public Lua API).

Comment: @macroland of course, otherwise check by luaL_checkudata would be always wrong